# InvalidOperationException with ExecuteOracleScalar()

Tags: oracle, select, invalidoperationexception

I need to select value from database:

```
    string AttrIdent = "";           

    OracleCommand sel_attr = new OracleCommand(@"

    select 
        IDENTIFIER_ 
    from 
        TBL_A_CUSTOM_FORM_BASE_ATTR
    where 
        TEMPLATEUUID in(
                        select UUID 
                        from TBL_A_CUSTOM_FORM_TEMPLATE
                        where PARENTUUID =:projid) 
        and IDENTIFIER_ in ('xxx',
                            'yyy',
                            'zzz')", conn);

    sel_attr.Parameters.Add("projid", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = id;
    sel_attr.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    AttrIdent = Convert.ToString(sel_attr.ExecuteOracleScalar());
```

but i got InvalidOperationException in

```
 AttrIdent = Convert.ToString(sel_attr.ExecuteOracleScalar());
```

What's I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an open connection?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is the code for second page. For first (index) page I'm used             try
            {
                conn.Open();
                adapter.Fill(dt);    
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing you don't have an open connection.